# Assign vector from pair<first,last>

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to construct a vector from data provided by a 3rd party lib.

The lib holds the data and provides access to it like this:

```
const uint8_t* data;
std::pair<const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*> getvalue() const {
  return std::make_pair(data + offset, data + length);
}
```

For further processing this data I'd put it into a vector, but I'd like to avoid multiple calling of `getvalue` and if possible I'd also avoid creating a variable.

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
std::pair<const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*> dataPtrs = 3rdpartydata.getvalue();
vector<uint8_t> data(dataPtrs.first, dataPtrs.second);
```

It is working, but is there any way to make it better/simpler?

Comment: auto [a,b] = _3rdpartydata.getvalue(); // in modern C++17+

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make it better. Adding `auto` is just syntactic sugar, it will make it look better, but logical value remains unattached.

Comment: The most "fancy" way to do it: `auto data = std::make_from_tuple<std::vector<uint8_t>>(thirdpartydata.getvalue());`, demo: https://www.godbolt.org/z/YMpaRv

Comment: @FantasticMrFox [`make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) forwards the elements of the tuple to the constructor.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox The output of `getvalue()` somewhat dangerously provides `begin` and `end` iterators to a (sub)range of the data, and promises that these are compatible and safe. It then makes use of the `vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` ctor of `std::vector` to construct a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: Yep, figured out that i was misinterpreting the constructor call straight after i posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Structured bindings

As of C++17, you can use [*structured bindings*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to bind the `first` and `second` members of `std::pair<...>` return value from `getvalue()`:

```
const auto [data_begin, data_end] = thirdpartydata.getvalue();
const std::vector<uint8_t> v(data_begin, data_end);
```

C++17 also introduced [*class template argument deduction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), meaning that you *may* omit the template argument in the declaration of `v` above, as it can be deduced:

```
const auto [data_begin, data_end] = thirdpartydata.getvalue();
const std::vector v(data_begin, data_end);
```

## `std::apply` and a generic lambda

Alternatively, you could make use of another C++17 feature, [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply), along with a generic lambda (C++14):

```
const auto v = std::apply([](auto a, auto b) { return std::vector(a, b); }, 
                          thirdpartydata.getvalue());
```

Note the use of class template argument deduction in the `return` statement of the lambda.